# How to deal with very long formulas

Tags: math-mode, formatting, equations, width

I have a very long formula that does not fit in the page. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)} 



\begin{equation*}
P_{j_k}(t) = \begin{cases}
    Q_{j,Standby_{init}} & \text{f"ur  } t < r_j   \\
        Q_{j,Run_k} & \text{f"ur  } 
        r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k-1} p_{j,i} + (k-1) * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non}
        \leq t <
        r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non} \\
        Q_{j,Standby_k} & \text{f"ur  } 
        r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non} 
        \leq t <
        r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + k * p_{j,non} \\
  \end{cases} \\
 \end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Comment: Looks like a duplicated. I'm not finding it.

Comment: your code does work there is somme error please post a working code

Comment: You mean a `formula`, not `formular`

Comment: My code always worked. I just do not know how to post it in such a code segment with copy and paste from my editor

Answer (score 1):

How about that?  I used the `aligned` and `medsize` (from `nccmath`) environments. I also loaded  `lmodern`, which is `T1`-encoded and has accented letters, for a correct hyphenation. Also, you can typeset accented letters directly (`ä` instead of  `{\"a}`).

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Geräte} \\
$\rightarrow$ \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)}

\begin{equation*}
  P_{j_k}(t) = \begin{cases}
  Q_{j,\text{Standby}_\text{init}} & \begin{medsize}\text{für } t < r_j,\end{medsize} \\[0.5ex]
  Q_{j,\text{Run}_k} & \! \begin{medsize}\begin{aligned}[t]\text{für }
  r_j + {} & ∑_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + ∑_{i=1}^{k-1} p_{j,i} + (k-1) * p_{j,\min} + (k-1) * p_{j,\text{non}}\leq t
  \\[-1ex]
  &< r_j + ∑_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + ∑_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,\min} + (k-1) * p_{j,\text{non}},
  \end{aligned}\end{medsize} \\[0.5ex]
  Q_{j,\text{Standby}_k} & \!\begin{medsize}\begin{aligned}[t]\text{für }
  r_j + {}& ∑_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + ∑ \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,\min} + (k-1) * p_{j,\text{non}}\leq t\\[-1ex]
  & < r_j + ∑ \limits_{i=1}^{k+1} s_{j,i} + ∑ \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,\min} + k * p_{j,\text{non}},
  \end{aligned}\end{medsize}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you like this

```
 \listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)} 



\begin{equation*}
P_{j_k}(t) = \begin{cases}
    Q_{j,Standby_{init}} & \text{f"ur  } t < r_j   \\
        Q_{j,Run_k} & 
        \begin{array}{ll}
        \text{f"ur  }r_j &+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i}
         + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k-1} p_{j,i} + (k-1) * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non}
        \leq t <
        r_j \\
        &+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non}
        \end{array} \\
        Q_{j,Standby_k} & 
        \begin{array}{ll}
        \text{f"ur  } &
        r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non} 
        \leq t <
        r_j \\
        &+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + k * p_{j,non} \end{array}\\
  \end{cases} \\
 \end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

or you can do this with array

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Unterbrechbare Ger{\"a}te} \\
 $\rightarrow$ \text{ mit n verschiedenen Phasen (n beliebig aber fest)} 



\begin{equation*}
P_{j_k}(t) = 
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lr@{}l}
Q_{j,Standby_{init}} & \text{f"ur  }&  t < r_j   \\
Q_{j,Run_k} & \text{f"ur  } &  r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i}
      + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k-1} p_{j,i} + (k-1) * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non}
      \leq t <  r_j \\
      && + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i} +\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non}\\
Q_{j,Standby_k} & \text{f"ur  }  & r_j + \sum \limits_{i=1}^k s_{j,i}
     + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + (k-1) * p_{j,non} 
     \leq t <  r_j \\
     &&+ \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k+1} s_{j,i} + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} p_{j,i} + k * p_{j,min} + k * p_{j,non}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi touhami, This does not look bad. But is there a way to get the "für" at the same vertical position as the "Q_j" like it is done in the first of those three cases.

Comment: @Gollum I edit my answer

Comment: You are still over the edge of the text area.  Use [draft] on the documentclass or add \noindent\hspace{\textwidth}\smash{\rule{1pt}{2in}} below the equation.